# How do we Clone a Github Repository With Backend Into my Device that Uses MERN

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mongodb, visual-studio, express

The Problem Is I Don't Know how to make schema's on mongo is there any  way that i can use the Owners already made schema's . I have install npm in my frontend as well as backend also made an env file that has my mongodb link. the frontend runs fine but backend thing does not work please help

I tried using my mongo id but i cant find the the scemas the owner used.